# Calling protocol function on viewDidLoad of UIViewController when the ViewController may or may not implement the protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I want to be able to call a protocol method on viewDidLoad only if the current UIViewController implements that protocol indie the Base class I am inheriting from. I am using the below Playground code to illustrate where I am at, at the moment and it called the function but crashes with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0).` error and nothing more.

```
import UIKit

protocol AccessibleProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
    func applyAccessibility()
}

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        (self as? AccessibleProtocol)?.applyAccessibility()
    }
}

class LoginViewController: BaseViewController {
    var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        passwordTextField = UITextField()
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension LoginViewController: AccessibleProtocol {
    func applyAccessibility() {
        self.passwordTextField.accessibilityLabel = "Enter Password"
    }
}

let loginViewController = LoginViewController()
loginViewController.viewDidLoad()
```

Comment: why are you calling viewDidLoad?

Comment: Because that is how I have it in my actual project, this is just an example to illustrate the same error I get so anybody trying to answer and plug this into the playground.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make the function of the protocol (kind of) optional.

```
import UIKit

protocol AccessibleProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
    func applyAccessibility()
}

extension AccessibleProtocol {
    func applyAccessibility() {}
}

class BaseViewController: UIViewController, AccessibleProtocol {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        applyAccessibility()
    }
}

class LoginViewController: BaseViewController {
    var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        passwordTextField = UITextField()
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension LoginViewController {
    func applyAccessibility() {
        self.passwordTextField.accessibilityLabel = "Enter Password"
    }
}

let loginViewController = LoginViewController()
loginViewController.viewDidLoad()
```

That way you can call de func from the protocol always. And If you didn't implemented it, it wont do anything.

Comment: I see where you are coming from with this but putting it in the Playground (and in app) the function is only called in the Protocol Extension of AccessibleProtocol and not the extension of LoginViewController.